# Calculations in a workbook stored in a variable

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro that:

- opens another workbook
- recalculates some ranges of cells there
- copies values over formulae in those ranges
- finally saves the result to archive

I want to store the workbook I'm working on in a variable and I got stuck with some errors with reasons unknown to me. The relevant part of my code is:

```
Dim bbgwb As Workbook
Dim filepath As String

filepath = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Task List").Range("I1").Value & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Task List").Range("D2").Value

Set bbgwb = Workbooks.Open(filepath)

bbgwb.Worksheets("FUND").Range("B142").Calculate
```

When I run the code, Excel opens the workbook I intend it to open but just after this I get "subscript out of range" error with the debugger pointing at the last code line I pasted. The workbook I open contains a worksheet called "FUND" and cell B142 there contains a formula, so I'm quite sure the problem is with badly written variable reference, but I have no idea what is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Does it give the same error if you put something like `bbgwb.Worksheets("FUND").Range("B142").Clear`?  If not, then it's probably the formula in B142 causing the error.  If yes, try bbgwb.Sheets(1).Range("A1") and go from there.

Comment: This worked, and is a good solution here as the workbooks I'm opening will all have just one worksheet so I can refer to them by number instead of name. Is it a general property of code doing something on workbooks stored in variables that you cannot refer to worksheets in them by name?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked.  No, AFAIK you can refer to any worksheets by name.  It might be that for some reason it doesn't think the name is "FUND".